# Wrapping v-data-table item slot (v-slot can only appear at the root level)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a component (wrapper component) that content v-data-table component

```
<child>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="tableHeader"
        :items="items"
        :item-key="itemsKey"
    >
        <slot name="data-table-custom-render" />
    </v-data-table>
</child>
```

how can I pass the custom properties rendering in the **parent component** knowing that **I have to use named slots** because i have another slots in the child component.

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <template slot="data-table-custom-render">
            <template #[`item.prop`]="{ item }"> # --> this give me error because it's not on the root level
                ...
            </template>
        </template>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Summary:
i want use a scoped slot inside a named slot !!